# ERPNEXT - docker frappe/erpnext-nginx:v14 - host not found in upstream "${BACKEND}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2

Tags: docker, nginx, erpnext, frappe

Anyone more are using the docker available in frappe/erpnext-nginx:v14?

I´m having the error

> host not found in upstream "${BACKEND}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2

Did I miss some enviroment vars?

```
root@ubuntu:/home/cleber# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES


root@ubuntu:/home/cleber# docker run --name erpnext frappe/erpnext-nginx:v14
Unable to find image 'frappe/erpnext-nginx:v14' locally
v14: Pulling from frappe/erpnext-nginx
df9b9388f04a: Pull complete 
de00536b0a20: Pull complete 
57b80225c5b2: Pull complete 
a884b9cd7ca7: Pull complete 
6d4033229ce9: Pull complete 
286837b3f72e: Pull complete 
f8a02597d6cc: Pull complete 
709ae10c88c2: Pull complete 
a179671e1a79: Pull complete 
feb2320fe500: Pull complete 
6f5c2cc0ed56: Pull complete 
dc5d8d2510a0: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:0d0cb4f50631164e94184d6c690354ab13b44f5d33246778b9b8aa62dd2d60d8
Status: Downloaded newer image for frappe/erpnext-nginx:v14
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/frappe-entrypoint.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
20-envsubst-on-templates.sh: Running envsubst on /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template to /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/06/05 13:10:40 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "${BACKEND}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "${BACKEND}" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
root@ubuntu:/home/cleber#
```

Answer (score 0):

`frappe/erpnext-nginx` image is not setup for independent use. You have to use it along with other services that are present in frappe_docker.

Clone frappe_docker repo, setup environment variables and run `docker compose up`.

```
git clone https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker
cd frappe_docker
docker compose up
```

More details on how to use frappe_docker are available here.

https://github.com/frappe/frappe_docker/blob/main/docs/setup-options.md